# window.webkit - How can I access this in my Chorme/Safari?

Tags: ios, webkit, mobile-safari, wkwebview

Hopefully it's a dummy question and you could guide me on how to solve this problem.

I'm working in a hybrid mobile application that was built in iOS and communicate with a Web Layer, using WKWebView. I'm using this post [here](http://www.joshuakehn.com/2014/10/29/using-javascript-with-wkwebview-in-ios-8.html) as reference.

My problem is occurring on the Web Layer side. When I try to access the webkit (example: window.webkit.messageHandlers.observe.postMessage(prop);), it seems that I don't have this object available (the object doesn't exist).

How can I access this in my Chome/Safari? Do I need to configure something in these browser?

Again, thanks in advance.